# Get Docker Container Names

Tags: linux, docker, containers

This command gives me a list of *running* container *IDs*:

```
docker ps -q
```

Is there a command to get the list of *names* of the containers?

Answer (score 129):

```
docker ps --format "{{.Names}}"
```

Comment: docker image ls

Comment: No response prompted

Comment: This command can now be written as 
"
docker container ls --format='{{.Names}}';
"

Answer (score 18):

You can combine [`docker ps`](https://docs.docker.com/docker/reference/commandline/ps/) with [`docker inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/docker/reference/commandline/inspect/), as I mentioned before in "[How do you list containers in Docker.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30070651/6309)":

```
docker inspect --format='{{.Name}}' $(sudo docker ps -aq --no-trunc)
docker inspect --format='{{.Name}}' $(sudo docker ps -aq --no-trunc) | cut -c2-
```

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31887258/get-docker-container-names/31887322#comment75834707_31887322) by [Chris Stryczynski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1663462/chris-stryczynski), it will print names with a '`/`' as a prefix.

```
vagrant@master:~$ docker inspect --format='{{.Name}}' $(sudo docker ps -aq --no-trunc)
/k8s_kubernetes-dashboard_kubernetes-dashboard-d9d8f48bc-vz59c_kube-system_b2abc584-730a_0
/k8s_POD_kubernetes-dashboard-d9d8f48bc-vz59c_kube-system_b2abc584-_0
/k8s_metrics-server_metrics-server-6fbfb84cdd-sjrgr_kube-system_e147bf91-7218-11e8-8266_0
/k8s_POD_metrics-server-6fbfb84cdd-sjrgr_kube-system_e147bf91-7218-11e8-8266-00155d380143_0
```

From [moby/moby issue 6705](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/6705):

> Inspect exposes the inner details of how docker is handling the container.
>   Names are prefixed with their parent and `/` == "the docker daemon".
>   That is why every name will have this prefixed.
>   This will be more important when nesting and multihost come into play.
>   The `/` is correct for the inspect command.

Hence the `| cut -c2-`.

More recently (June 2017), there is a proposal ([moby/moby issue 29997](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29997)) for removing the '`/`':

> the leading slash is there for historical reasons (mainly because of the legacy container-linking)

So far (June 2018), no PR has been fully implemented to get rid of the leading '`/`'.

Comment: This has a slash prepended for each container name.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski Sorry, I completely missed your comment at the time. I have edited the answer to explain why there is a leading '/', and how to remove it.

Answer (score 12):

You could do that with this command inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840409/how-do-you-list-containers-in-docker-io):

```
docker inspect --format='{{.Name}}' $(sudo docker ps -aq --no-trunc)
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use following command to display names of container

```
docker ps -a --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}"
```

Here is reference link for more information about ps command
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/

Answer (score 10):

You can also do it using awk:

```
docker ps -a | awk '{print $NF}'
```

`$NF` indicates the last column of the input, which in `docker ps -a` command is Names.

Comment: This, however, also outputs the column header - which is not desired

Comment: as @ascendants suggested, to exclude column headers use:
`docker ps -a | awk '{ if( FNR>1 ) { print $NF }'`
FNR *indicates to skip the first entry (the column header)*

Answer (score 3):

My requirement is get the **container user name** to login into the container (I need use `docker exec -it --user` to login container). Use `docker inspect` + `container id` and `grep` `user` or `name` then you can get the **Container User Name** and login into the container.

Example:

```
    # docker inspect 5791b95933ef |grep -i user
```

Answer (score 0):

```
docker ps -a --format "{{.Names}}" --filter="id=<id>"
```

id is the CONTAINER ID.

Pass the name as an environment variable when instantiating the container