# How can I see the full command string in the command column when listing containers?

Tags: docker

It is a complement of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840409/how-to-list-containers-in-docker), where the typical solution is to use the command `sudo docker container ls` that displays

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             ...
4114e655e2b1        xx/yy                 "/bin/sh -c 'exec po…"   3 days ago          ...
```

The problem here is **how can I see the full COMMAND column content?**

PS: no one use the `--format` option, how do I use it in the simplest plug-and-play way?

Comment: `docker ps --no-trunc  --format "{{.Command}}"`

Comment: Another option is you could use something like -> https://www.portainer.io/  you can then click on the container and get way more info than can practically be displayed on a single line of a terminal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To see the full command output, you have to use the `--no-trunc` option

```
docker container ls --no-trunc
```

Now if you want to reduce the output to the info you find relevant, you can use the `--format` option. Here is an example for name and command (inspired from https://container42.com/2016/03/27/docker-quicktip-7-psformat/):

```
docker container ls --no-trunc --format '{{.Names}}\t{{.Command}}'
```

Answer (score 1):

`docker inspect $containerID --format '{{.Path}} {{.Args}}'` - where $containerID is your container's id.

`docker inspect` is a really handy tool that can tell you a lot about your container / image.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, more one alternative to show information.