# Docker ps not showing my container it shows in ps-a

Tags: docker

Hi i am new user on ubuntu during my practice i install docker by

```
sudo apt install docker.io
```

Check the version and all thing properly i started working
after it i pull the ubuntu image by

```
sudo docker pull ubuntu
```

after it i check the image by

```
sudo docker images
```

image is shown by all details
after that i make the container by

```
sudo docker container run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

when i try to see my container by

```
sudo docker ps
```

the result is blank

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

But when i write this command

```
sudu docker ps -a
```

this shows me the container

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS               NAMES
110359388f2d        ubuntu              "/bin/bash"         21 hours ago        Exited (0) 21 hours ago                       stupefied_dewdney
```

How to fix this? Why my container is not showing in docker ps ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list containers in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840409/how-to-list-containers-in-docker)

Comment: once you get the answer kindly accept the answer so that this will help others

Answer (score 8):

So there is a difference between `docker ps` and `docker ps -a`

`docker ps`: shows the running container on your host
`docker ps -a`: this shows running and exited containers on the host.

So in your case your container is exited, means not running on the host thats why this shows in `docker ps -a`

Answer (score 1):

It's not showing as the container has exited.

`docker ps` only shows running containers while passing the `-a` flag shows all containers.
If you want your container to show up, you will have to start it by using `docker container start`

Comment: if container has single command it will stop and again `docker ps` will show nothing

Comment: @d0niek thank you soo much when i run the container by sudo docker container run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied
root@c3c0fbd35bd9:/# 
thisis showing